# Eclipse inspection (Ctrl + Shift + I) equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition)

Tags: eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Under Eclipse I can inspect expressions/variables in debug mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. In IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition), I can add expressions/variables to the watches, but on the next debug they are lost.

Is there any way to inspect variables and expressions on the fly when I'm debugging?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`Quick evaluate expression` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> (or on a Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>) gives me exactly what I want.

Comment: Note that this shortcut key might conflict with an Intel graphics card shortcut for resetting graphics properties (resolution, monitors etc.) If it does, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108927/ctrl-alt-f8-disconnects-displays#35109007) for how to disable it.

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean "Evaluate expression" action <kbd>Alt + F8</kbd>?

Many more useful shortcuts are in [Intellij Reference Card](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf).

Comment: not exactly, with Alt + F8 i must execute the evaluation. But i still have a solution - "Quick evaluate expression" with Ctrl + Alt + F8.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> will work.
This shortcut may trigger the Intel HD Graphics hotkey for resetting display settings.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + `Left Mouse Key` will also work.

If you want to view/edit the shortcuts, you can go to `Settings` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)   ->  `Keymap` and search for `Quick Evaluate Expression`

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> in case of Intellij Idea 2019.2 and Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

In mac, alt+clicking variables help !