# How do I connect my monitor to my desktop after pressing ctrl + alt +f8

Tags: screen, desktop, bios

I was running Bluestacks on my desktop and I accidentally pressed ctrl + alt + f8. Now the screen keeps saying input signal out of range change settings to 1440X900-60Hz I tried some other solutions like going into safe mode and rebooting but it still doesn't work I can't go to settings but I can go to the bios menu. How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Just follow the https://stackoverflow.com/a/52520504/1266040